# Leaflet Draw - Selecting 1 Draw Option then another causes Drawing to drag map instead of shape

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

When attempting to draw, if you first select Draw Circle then select Draw Rectangle then go to click on the map, instead of beginning the drawing and dragging the shape out, the shape gets an initial placement and the map drags instead. You can do the opposite as well (select Rectangle then Circle then click/drag).

You can see this behavior here: http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/full.html
Draw Circle the click/drag works Fine. Draw Rectangle then click/drag works fine. Draw Circle then Draw Rectangle then click/drag causes map to begin dragging instead of shape.

This does not seem to be an issue when going between Circle-Polygon or Rectangle-Polygon, only Circle-Rectangle.

I tried debugging to see if any errors or weird events were being thrown but no such luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Leaflet-Draw is not maintained anymore. Try Leaflet-Geoman instead.